# Change Date Format in Form Results

Tags: php, sql, datetime, select

I am trying to change the format of how the date appears on the output from my form. I have searched the internet and I believe this is what I need to do:

```
SELECT datetime(date_submitted,'%m/%d/%Y') as date_submitted FROM guestquestionnaire
```

- date_submitted is the name of this element in my database
- datetime is the type of element
- guestquestionnaire is the name of my table

But it's giving me a blank page as though something is wrong. Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more code. I am using PDO and I ideally want the date format at mm/dd/yyyy. If I can also get the time format as 11:11 am (as an example) that would be great too!!

Update - Code:

```
<?php

try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
class guestquestionnaireEntry {
    public $id, $date_submitted, 
        $entry;

        public function __construct()
    {

 $this->entry = "
         <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td width='60%'><a href=\"?ID={$this->ID}\">ID</a> </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->date_submitted}</td></tr>

<table border='1' align='center'>

        <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td></tr>

        </table>";

    }
}

        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted, '%m/%d/%Y') AS date_submitted FROM guestquestionnaire


// Checks if the submitted is a number. If so, isolates the ID and adds "where" clause
$id      =   (!empty($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']))? " where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
// Add the $id to the end of the string
// A single call would be SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire where ID = '1'
$query   =   $handler->query("SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire{$id}");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');

while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $r->entry, '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: a blank page hints more towards a php syntax, or other error, not your query.

Comment: do you store the date in proper format in database. i.e. is the date column data type is date?

Comment: The type is 'datetime' in the database

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted, '%m/%d/%Y') AS date_submitted 
FROM guestquestionnaire
```

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't seem to go through though; still a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT date_format(`date_submitted`,'%m/%d/%Y') as `date_submitted` FROM `guestquestionnaire`
```

### Update:

Now that the full code has been posted it appears the problems did not lie with the sql. I have not tested the following but it looks more or less ok so I hope it works.

```
<?php

    try {
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
        $handler->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        die( $e->getMessage() );
    }

    class guestquestionnaireEntry {
        public $id, $date_submitted,$entry;
        public function render(){
            return "
             <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                <td width='60%'>
                    <a href=\"?id={$this->id}\">ID</a>
                </td>
                <td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->date_submitted}</td>
            </tr>
            <table border='1' align='center'>
                <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>
                    <td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td>
                </tr>
            </table>";
        }
    }

    $id     =  !empty( $_GET['ID'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['ID'] ) ? "where `ID`='".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
    $sql     =  trim("select * from `guestquestionnaire` {$id}");

    $query  =   $handler->query( $sql );
    $result =   $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry' );

    foreach( $result as $obj ) echo $obj->render();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't seem to go through though; still a blank page.

Comment: If it is not the sql at fault then you would need to post more code so that others can deduce where the faults lie

Comment: @CodingBoy Boy any idea what might be causing the blank page?

Comment: if i am understanding your question ,you want is to retrive date and time which is stored in date_sumitted  column in database..??

Comment: Correct. It already retrieves the date and time, I just want to change the format that it comes through (i.e. not YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: means retrieved date is in YYYY-MM-DD format but you want to print this date in MM-DD-YYYY format..

Comment: i understand the problem..please check my Answer once, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

select convert(varchar(),YourDateColumn,103) from YourTable

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english..

if i am understanding your question ,you want is to retrive date and time which is in DateTime format and stored in date_sumitted column in database..

try below code once .. works for me. i hope It will be helpful to you

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted, '%m/%d/%Y')  AS date_submitted FROM guestquestionnaire ");
$row = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($row as $key) 
    {
        $date = $key['date_submitted'];
        echo $date;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that doesn't seem to work though. It just gives me blank results (i.e. nothing there).

Comment: Yes. Both give me blank data.

Comment: hmm..it means i failed to help you..Actually my codes are giving the expect results that's why i post answer..